# Rewriting where functions to lambda

Tags: haskell, lambda

I'm trying to rewrite a function to a good lambda style
Currently, I have a double where function. And i connect the two with a combination function.
But I can probably pull this off in way fewer lines by using lambda.

```
generateAllSplits :: Dataset -> [(Split, Dataset, Dataset)]
generateAllSplits dataset = zipWith combfunc splits tuples 
 where splits = getAllFeatureSplits dataset
       tuples = map (splitOnFeature dataset) splits

combfunc :: Split -> (Dataset, Dataset) -> (Split, Dataset, Dataset)
combfunc split (f,s) = (split,f,s)
```

I can probably find it out myself, but I can just not find a good source or examples on writing lambda (from where).

Edit: I first tried to remove the combfunc by using let instead.
This is the result now:

```
generateAllSplits' :: Dataset -> [(Split, Dataset, Dataset)]
generateAllSplits' dataset = let x = getAllFeatureSplits dataset
                                 y = map (splitOnFeature dataset) x
                             in zip3 x (map fst y) (map snd y)
```

My question still stands: How can I rewrite to a lambda style?

Answer (score 2):

Any function definition in Haskell is just alternative syntax for lambdas (plus possibly `case` matching and/or `let` bindings, but neither of these are needed in `combfunc` because it has only a single clause and no `where` bindings).

Here, you have

```
combfunc :: Split -> (Dataset, Dataset) -> (Split, Dataset, Dataset)
combfunc = \split (f,s) -> (split,f,s)
```

At this point, it's just a definition of the same form as `x = 4 + 9`, which allows you to replace any occurence of `x` with the expression `4 + 9` (possibly surrounded by parentheses, depending on the context). You can do that just as well also in your code.